# How to refresh the data without reloading the page using data-bind

Tags: data-binding, python-2.7, knockout.js, django-views

I am using knockout.js in my django project and having problem in post method in javascript. I tried to rebind or re-initialized the list but it didn't work.

Eg: I am showing table data with 10 rows..I want on button click I get another data with 5 rows and want to reload that data on table without reloading the page.

Does any one knows the solution .. Below is my code for knockout.js, html and view.py page:

javascript:

```
function makeShowObjectList(model, d_url, no_num, detail_per_page, b, fruit) {
var showobjectList = ko.observableArray([]);


 $.post(d_url, data, function (response_data) {
                // here we have applied code to set new data in showobjectList
                if (!showobjectList.is_ready)
                {   

                   //Here we are trying to relaod the list on the page but did'nt work
                    FViewModel.showobjectList=showobjectList;
                     showobjectList.is_ready = true;
                    showobjectList.onready();
                    ko.mapping.fromJSshowobjectList, {}, self); }
                }
            }, 'json');

}
function fruitFilterItem( n, i ) {
    this.n = n;
    this.i   = i;
}
var FViewModel=function(c_data)
{
    var self = this;
    self.abc= ko.observable(null);
        this.optionsText = ko.observable();
        this.fruitFilter = ko.observableArray([
        new fruitFilterItem( "Mango", 2 ),
        new fruitFilterItem( "Banana", 1 ),
        new fruitFilterItem( "Grapes", 3 )
    ]);
    this.selectedfruit = ko.observable();
    this.VegeFilter = ko.observableArray([
        new fruitFilterItem( "Tomato", "Tomato" ),
        new fruitFilterItem( "Patato", "Patato" ),
        new fruitFilterItem( "Onion", "Onion" ),

    ]);
    this.selectedVege = ko.observable();

    self.showtList = makeShowObjectList(BucketViewModel, urls.get_fruit_info, self.fruit_page, self.num_fruit, self.bbq, 

self.selectedfruit());
        self.setShowType = function(d, ele) {
        this.get_updates = function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(searchList(), self);};


          self.showtList = makeShowObjectList(BucketViewModel, urls.get_fruit_info, self.fruit_page, self.num_fruit, self.b,  self.selectedfruit()); 
         self.showtList();


    }

 self.ShowmessageList = function () {
        return self.showtList;
    }


}
```

HTML:

```
<script>
VarModel = new FViewModel(c_data);
$(function() {
       function get_updates () {
       $.getJSON('/new-lines.json', function(c_data) {
       var VarModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(choices_data);

           ko.applyBindings(VarModel );


             });
```

}
ko.applyBindings(VarModel);

```
</script>
<body>
<select id="fruit" name="fruit"  style="width:200px;" data-bind = "   
        value: selectedfruit,
        options:        fruitFilter,
        optionsText:    'n', 
        optionsValue:   'i',   
        optionsCaption: 'Select a fruit'
    ">

        </select>

        <select style="width:180px;" data-bind = "   
        value: selectedVege,
        options:        VegeFilter,
        optionsText:    'n', 
        optionsValue:   'i',   
        optionsCaption: 'Select a Vege'
    ">
```

//here we are showing our columns

```
</body>
```

Views.py:

```
def urls.get_fruit_info(request):

      //we are calculating the page_object here

      response_object = {
        'page': page_object,
        'no_not': FruitRecipient.objects.filter(user=request.member, add_at=None).count()
      }
      return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_object, indent=3))
```

I would be thankful if any one could help me out in sorting my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use ko.mapping its a plugin that you can download, it only updates the observables that have changed between two states, thus only the members that have changed will be re re-rendered in the view

Comment: I have downloaded knockout.mappings-latest.js(version 2.0). And then have applied it into my code.But I am facing the same issue as earlier that I am able to get the data on post but I am not able to reload that data on table. I have updated my code above after using ko.mappings...Please help me out where I am going wrong..If possible I would be delighted if any one could correct my code...Thanks in advance..